# Verify that the directory is a bundle

Tags: objective-c, bundle

ALL,

I'm trying to rewrite some old code with the new OSX Cocoa API.

I got a suggestion to use

`-[NSWorkspace openApplicationAtURL:configuration:completionHandler:]`

to open and execute a bundle, however I'd like to do some sanity check first.

So my code will look like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPath isDirectory:YES];
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:url];
if( bundle == nil )
{
    printf( "Not a bundle!!";
    return -1;
}
NSWorkspace *ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
NSRunningApplication *app = [ws ...];
```

Am I right? Or there is a better way to do that?

Also, I think I don't need to delete NSBundle object, right?

TIA!

[EDIT]

I tried to produce the following code:

```
NSWorkspace *ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
NSRunningApplication *app = [ws launchApplicationAtURL:url options:NSWorkspaceLaunchAsync
                                         configuration:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:params forKey:NSWorkspaceLaunchConfigurationArguments]
                                         error:&error];
[params release];

if( app != nil )
    pid = [app processIdentifier];
```

However when I tried to supply `/bin/ls` I git `pid` as `-1`.

Can I successfully rely on the fact that this method will return -1 on non-bundle application?

[/EDIT]

Comment: Have you tried it? What happens when you pass `@"/tmp"` as `myPath`?

Comment: @CRD, I didn't try it yet, but hoping that there is better solution...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know that a given URL is an application, get and check the `NSURLIsApplicationKey` resource of the `NSURL`.

However, there's really no need to do this: `-openApplicationAtURL:configuration:completionHandler:` will perform whatever sanity checks are appropriate and fail if there's a problem. So pre-flighting it will just do this preliminary work twice.

Comment: I am trying to rewrite old Carbon code. There all those sanity checks was performed. Now I presume that in case of failure `openApplicationAtURL` or `launchApplicationAtURL` will just return `nil`, right?

Comment: Then this is a great opportunity to jettison old crusty code! ;) From the documentation: "If the application could not be launched, `nil` is returned and the error is specified in `error`."

Comment: please see my edit to the question. Any suggestions?

Comment: I doubt there's any guarantee of particular PID value if the application couldn't be opened. If you want to know if there was a problem launching the app, I'd suggest examining the `NSError` returned ... ;)